# UiBinder FlexTable style

Tags: css, gwt, uibinder, flextable

I want to add different styles to different rows, Which is the best way?

I'm trying this (it doesnt works, no error but no changes):

- TWO INTERFACES:

public interface StatiscticsTableResources extends ClientBundle {

```
public static final StatiscticsTableResources INSTANCE = GWT.create(StatiscticsTableResources.class);

@Source("StatisticsTableCss.css")
StatisticsTableCss css();
```

}

public interface StatisticsTableCss extends CssResource {

```
String tableOddRow();
```

}

- THE CSS

.tableOddRow {
    background-color: #aeaaa2;
    color: blue;
}

- APLLYING THE STYLE

ftStatistics.getRowFormatter().addStyleName(i, StatiscticsTableResources.INSTANCE.css().tableOddRow());

Comment: Have you checked (for example, with Firebug) that the style actually is applied? You can mark it as `@external` in the CSS file so that the GWT compiler won't obfuscate its name - makes it easier to debug.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Wild guess, you've forgotten to inject the style sheet. Somewhere at the top of the class where you apply the style, add this line:

```
static { StatisticsTableResources.INSTANCE.css().ensureInjected(); }
```